# Custom validation summary in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm working on a client validation in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I'm trying to override default validation summary from unobtrusive jquery validation. There's a method "OnErrors", which I need to override. I found a solution, but for me it works only with single errors. Here is the code:

```
$(function () {   
var settings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;

var oldErrorFunction = settings.errorPlacement;
var oldErrorsFunction = settings.invalidHandler;
var oldSucessFunction = settings.success;


settings.invalidHandler = function (form, validator) {        
    alert("Form is invalid");
    oldErrorsFunction(form, validator);
}

settings.errorPlacement = function (error, inputElement) {
    $(".validation-summary-errors").append("single error ");
    var errorsNumber = 0;
        $(".validation-summary-errors li").each(function () {
            errorsNumber++;        
        });              
    oldErrorFunction(error, inputElement);        
}    
settings.success = function (error) {
    oldSucessFunction(error);
}
```

});

errorPlacement (for every single error) works well , but invalidHandler (for all errors at once) never fires.

How would you handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this working for us:

```
form.unbind("invalid-form.validate", form.validate().settings.invalidHandler); // Unbind the existing invalidHandler
form.validate().settings.invalidHandler = $.proxy(customValidationSummary, form); // Replace invalidHandler with a custom one
form.bind("invalid-form.validate", form.validate().settings.invalidHandler); // Rebind the new invalidHandler
```